# How i Can Change Ubuntu 20.04 Logo

Tags: gnome, 20.04, customization, 20.10, logo

Changing /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png file no longer works for me. Its works in 18.04 but i want change for 20.04.

How i can change this logo for my customized distro?
[image]

Comment: I would assume (so not an answer) that the hicolor in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png` is the name of a theme(?) if so... you are not using hicolor but another theme so adjust the directory to the theme used. Maybe do a `locate ubuntu-logo-icon.png` and change them all to your image (with a backup so you can restore ;-) )?

Comment: Changing icons (not theme) solved this problem. Thank you!